# Apache Beam , mock external Clients initialized in @Setup Lifecycle method of DoFn

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have created the following DoFn class, but i am not sure, how to mock APIClient, since creating the instance of JsonToGenericRecordMapper in Junit with mocked APICall object, is getting overridden with @setup method, which is creating actual instance of APICall ?

```
public class JsonToGenericRecordMapper extends DoFn<String, GenericRecord> {
    
    private APICall apiCall;
    
     @setup
     public void setup () 
    {
        api = new APICall();
    }
    
    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext processContext) {

        String enrichedItemCost = processContext.element();

        Schema schema = CommonUtils.schema;
        GenericRecord genericRecord = new GenericData.Record(schema);
        genericRecord.put(CommonUtils.SCHEMA_FIELD_KEY, enrichedItemCost);

        processContext.output(genericRecord);
    }
}




TestPipeline testPipeline = TestPipeline.create();
APICAll apiCall = Mockito.mock(APICall.class);
dataPCollection.apply(new JsonToGenericRecordMapper(apiCall));
```

Comment: The main issue with mocking APIClient in your DoFn isn't due to it being overridden in the @Setup method, but rather the serialization process in Apache Beam. Mock objects generally can't be serialized for distributed execution, affecting their behavior. Consider using serializable fakes, as I described in my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/77984125/2315526, as an alternative to ensure compatibility with Beam's execution model.

Answer (score 0):

you can create two constructors (an empty and one one with the APICall parameter), and use one of them for testing, something like that (I just extended your example to get the point, so it's just an example):

```
public class JsonToGenericRecordMapper extends DoFn<String, GenericRecord> {

private APICall apiCall;

public JsonToGenericRecordMapper() {
}

public JsonToGenericRecordMapper(APICall apiCall) {
    this.apiCall = apiCall;
}


 @setup
 public void setup () 
 { 
    if(apiCall==null) {
        api = new APICall();
    }
 }

@ProcessElement
public void processElement(ProcessContext processContext) {

    String enrichedItemCost = processContext.element();

    Schema schema = CommonUtils.schema;
    GenericRecord genericRecord = new GenericData.Record(schema);
    genericRecord.put(CommonUtils.SCHEMA_FIELD_KEY, enrichedItemCost);

    processContext.output(genericRecord);
  }
}

TestPipeline testPipeline = TestPipeline.create();
APICAll apiCall = Mockito.mock(APICall.class);
dataPCollection.apply(new JsonToGenericRecordMapper(apiCall));
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing idea. But need to remember, in Apache Beam, making mocks for testing not always work because of serialization when running pipeline. Mock objects might not keep correctly through this, causing problems. Maybe better to look at other ways like using fakes that can serialize.

Answer (score 0):

Mocking components of DoFn doesn't work well because mocks don't survive the serialization process during pipeline execution. Instead of mocks, it's better to use fakes, as suggested in the Beam documentation in the 'Use Fakes' section (https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/testing/). Here's how I managed to unit test DoFn with a working implementation in kotlin:

JsonToGenericRecordMapper

```
class JsonToGenericRecordMapper : DoFn<String?, GenericRecord?>() {
    @Transient
    private var apiClient: ApiClient? = null

    @Setup
    fun setup() {
        // Initial setup for non-test execution
        apiClient = ApiClient()
    }

    @ProcessElement
    fun processElement(processContext: ProcessContext) {
        var response = apiClient?.call()
        // Continue with your processElement logic
    }

    @VisibleForTesting
    fun setApiClientForTests(client: ApiClient) {
        this.apiClient = client
    }
}
```

ApiClient with the fake

```
import java.io.Serializable as JavaSerializable

open class ApiClient : JavaSerializable {
    open fun call(): String {
        // Actual API call
        return "API Response"
    }
}

class FakeApiClient : ApiClient() {
    override fun call(): String {
        // Mocked API call
        return "Mocked response"
    }
}
```

The Test

```
class JsonToGenericRecordMapperTest {
        @get:Rule
        val pipeline = TestPipeline.create()
    
        @Test
        fun `test JsonToGenericRecordMapper processes elements correctly`() {
            val fakeApiClient = FakeApiClient()
            val mapper = JsonToGenericRecordMapper()
                .apply {
                    setApiClientForTests(fakeApiClient)
                }
    
            val expectedOutput = /* Define your expected output */
            val input = "Test input"
    
            // Prepare the input PCollection
            val inputPCollection = pipeline.apply(Create.of(input))
    
            // Apply the DoFn
            val output: PCollection = inputPCollection.apply(
                ParDo.of(
                    mapper
                )
            )
    
            PAssert.that(output).containsInAnyOrder(expectedOutput)
            pipeline.run().waitUntilFinish()
        }
    }
```

However, you can still use mocking effectively within fake objects. This strategy is particularly useful when you need to simulate complex behaviors or external dependencies, such as OAuth token generation, within your test environment. To facilitate mocking in Kotlin, especially when using Gradle, ensure you include the Mockito Kotlin library in your project dependencies. Here's the required dependency:

Add to your build.gradle.kts (Kotlin DSL):

```
testImplementation group: 'org.mockito.kotlin', name: 'mockito-kotlin', version: '5.2.1'
```

JsonToGenericRecordMapper

```
import com.google.auth.oauth2.IdToken
    
class JsonToGenericRecordMapper : DoFn<String?, GenericRecord?>() {

    @Transient
    private var apiClient: ApiClient? = null

    @Setup
    fun setup() {
        apiClient = ApiClient()
    }

    @ProcessElement
    fun processElement(processContext: ProcessContext) {
        // Example of using the IdToken within the processElement method
        val idToken = apiClient?.createIdToken()
        val accessToken = idToken.tokenValue
    }
}
```

Client and fake client

```
open class ApiClient : JavaSerializable {
    open fun createIdToken(): IdToken {
        /* actual generation logic here */
        return IdToken.create("actual token")
    }
}

import org.mockito.kotlin.mock
import org.mockito.kotlin.whenever

class FakeApiClient : ApiClient() {
    override fun createIdToken(): IdToken {
        val fakeTokenIdToken: IdToken = mock()  
        whenever(fakeTokenIdToken.tokenValue).thenReturn("fake token")
        return fakeTokenIdToken
    }
}
```